# Difference Between Flux.create and Flux.generate

Tags: project-reactor

What is the difference between [`Flux.create`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#create-java.util.function.Consumer-reactor.core.publisher.FluxSink.OverflowStrategy-) and [`Flux.generate`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#generate-java.util.function.Consumer-)? I am looking--ideally with an example use case--to understand when I should use one or the other.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### In short:

> `Flux::create` doesn't react to changes in the state of the app while `Flux::generate` does.

---

### The long version

#### `Flux::create`

You will use it when you want to calculate multiple (0...infinity) values which are not influenced by the state of your app and the state of your *pipeline* (your *pipeline* == the chain of operations which comes *after* `Flux::create` == *downstream*).

Why? Because the method which you sent to `Flux::create` keeps calculating elements (or none). The *downstream* will determine how many elements (elements == *next signals*) it wants and if he can't keep up, those elements which are already emitted will be removed/buffered in some strategy (by default they will be buffered until the *downstream* will ask for more).

The first and easiest use case is for emitting values which you, theoretically, could sum to a collection and only then take each element and do something with it:

```java
Flux<String> articlesFlux = Flux.create((FluxSink<String> sink) -> {
/* get all the latest article from a server and emit them one by one to downstream. */
List<String> articals = getArticalsFromServer();
articals.forEach(sink::next);
});
```

As you can see, `Flux.create` is used for interaction between blocking method (`getArticalsFromServer`) to asynchronous code.

I'm sure there are other use cases for `Flux.create`.

---

#### `Flux::generate`

```java
Flux.generate((SynchronousSink<Integer> synchronousSink) -> {
        synchronousSink.next(1);
    })
    .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println(number))
    .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println(number + 4))
    .subscribe();
```

The output will be `1 5 1 5 1 5................forever`

**In each invocation** of the method you sent to `Flux::generate`, `synchronousSink` can only emits: `onSubscribe onNext? (onError | onComplete)?`.

It means that `Flux::generate` will **calculate and emit** values **on demand**. When should you use it? In cases where it's too expensive to calculate elements which may not be used *downstream* or the events which you emit are influenced by the state of the app or from the state of your *pipeline* (your *pipeline* == the chain of operations which comes *after* `Flux::create` == *downstream*).

For example, if you are building a torrent application then you are receiving blocks of data in real time. You could use `Flux::generate` to give tasks (blocks to download) to multiple threads and you will calculate the block you want to download inside `Flux::generate` only when some thread is asking. So you will emit only blocks you don't have. The same algorithm with `Flux::create` will fail because `Flux::create` will emit all the blocks we don't have and if some blocks failed to be downloaded then we have a problem. because `Flux::create` doesn't react to changes in the state of the app while `Flux::generate` does.

Comment: Thanks. Your description for `Flux::generate` and `Flux::create` blocking-to-asynchronous-interaction makes sense, but I don't understand _from multiple threads outside `Flux::create`. Are you specifically calling out that `create` is incapable of handling multiple asynchronous consumers, since the pre-fetched data is only available to one consumer?

Comment: After reading the documentation again, it's better to use pre-defined processors than exposing the `FluxSink` object outside of `Flux::create` (When you want to use `FluxSink` from multiple threads; outside of `Flux::create`). Source: http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#processor-overview

Comment: BTW, the reactor docs state "If you block within the create lambda, you expose yourself to deadlocks and similar side effects." And it seems that you have a blocking call in your example...

Comment: there are no deadlocks.. you should avoid them at all cost. there is 99% other solution. About the side-effects and blocking - Your app **will** have side effects and remmeber that **most** of Java API is blocking API.. so there is not much other ways to convert them to async/reactive APIs.

Comment: @StavAlfi "After reading the documentation again, it's better to use pre-defined processors than exposing the FluxSink object outside of Flux::create (When you want to use FluxSink from multiple threads; outside of Flux::create)" Could you quote the exact sentences that lead you to this conclusion ? I don't see anything that would imply that in the docs

Comment: @jonenst sorry, im not in the loop anymore. i did not write any java code in the last 2 years. feel free to edit my answer if you think that something is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558911/is-it-safe-to-use-the-same-fluxsink-from-multiple-threads-concurrently/52581994?noredirect=1#comment112684383_52581994 for a possible explanation

Answer (score 19):

## **Create:**

[image]

- Accepts a `Consumer<FluxSink<T>>`
- Consumer is invoked only once per subscriber
- Consumer can emit 0..N elements immediately
- Publisher is not aware of downstream state. So we need to provide Overflow strategy as an additional parameter
- We can get the reference of **FluxSink** using which we could keep on emitting elements as and when required using multiple threads.

## **Generate:**

[image]

- Accepts a `Consumer<SynchronousSink<T>>`
- Consumer is invoked again and again based on the downstream demand
- Consumer can emit only one element at the max with an optional complete/error signal.
- Publisher produces elements based on the downstream demand
- We can get the reference of **SynchronousSink**. But it might not be really useful as we could emit only one element

Check this [blog](http://www.vinsguru.com/reactive-programming-flux-create-vs-generate/) for more details.

Comment: The blog that you added made things crystal clear. Thanks @Vins.