# Is it safe to use the same FluxSink from multiple threads concurrently

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I know a `Publisher` must not publish concurrently, but if I use `Flux#create(FluxSink)`, can I safely call `FluxSink#next` concurrently?

In other words, does Spring have internal magic that ensures proper serial publishing of events even if `FluxSink#next` is called concurrently?

```
public class FluxTest {

    private final Map<String, FluxSink<Item>> sinks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    // Store a new sink for the given ID
    public void start(String id) {
        Flux.create(sink -> sinks.put(id, sink));
    }

    // Called from different threads
    public void publish(String id, Item item) {
        sinks.get(id).next(item); //<----------- Is this safe??
    }
}
```

It *sounds to me* like [this paragraph](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.create) in the official guide indicates that the above is indeed safe, but I'm not very confident in my understanding.

> `create` is a more advanced form of programmatic creation of a Flux which is suitable for multiple emissions per round, even from multiple threads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [`Flux.create`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/v3.2.0.RELEASE/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.java#L700) produces a [`SerializedSink`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/v3.2.0.RELEASE/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxCreate.java#L93) that is safe to use from multiple threads for `next` calls

Comment: I read from multiple answers on stackoverflow that escaping the sink from the lambda is not recommended (for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/56063933 and its comments) and that you must use processors instead. Do you have info on this ? thanks

Comment: I think that comment was more about the fact that these `FluxSink` are created _per `Subscription`_, so capturing one in a field can be misleading in case of multiple subscriptions to the `Flux.create(...)`. Note that in 3.4 we're introducing a new flavor of `Sinks` that is more tailored towards this "standalone in a field with multiple possible subscription" usage pattern. The thread safety comment still stands, eg. it is possible to spawn multiple threads from the `Flux.create` and have each feed data to the same `FluxSink`.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I was wondering about the difference between this example and the one from the docs where an event listener is created and captures the sink in its method. In both cases, the sink "escapes". I think you're right, the real difference is having multiple objects in case of multiple subscriptions. Or you could add the sinks to a list in a field instead.
Thanks for the heads up for the 3.4.

Comment: @SimonBaslé Regarding the new Sinks class in 3.4, is it possible to use `StandaloneFluxSink<Integer> sink = Sinks.multicast()` that sink from multiple threads? Or is the only way to create a `SerailizedSink` through `Flux.create`? My use case is from incoming http requests (possible on different threads?) I push data to a service which does some calculations.

Comment: @Dachstein (StandaloneFluxSink is from an outdated Milestone or RC) `Sinks.Many` by default are _detecting_ multi-threaded usage and failing. They have a `tryEmitNext` API that will immediately return an enum, one of which represents the fact that parallel emission was attempted. you can then choose to optimistically retry/busy loop, or consider that an error.

Comment: @SimonBaslé thanks for the explanation. Can I just ask you one more? `SerializedSink` can only be created through `Flux.create` or is there a way to get it also through calling methods in the Sinks class?

Comment: only from Flux create. it is intended to be created one sink per subscription