# Project Reactor, using a Flux sink outside of the creation lambda

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

- When my service starts up, I want to construct a simple pipeline.
- I'd like to isolate the Flux sink, or a Processor, to emit events with.
- Events will be coming in from multiple threads and should be processed according to the pipeline's `subscribeOn()` specification, but everything seems to run on the `main` thread.
- What is the best approach? I've attached my attempts below.
- (I'm using reactor-core v3.2.8.RELEASE.)

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import reactor.core.publisher.DirectProcessor;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.FluxProcessor;
import reactor.core.publisher.FluxSink;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

/**
 * I want to construct my React pipelines during creation,
 * then emit events over the lifetime of my services.
 */
public class React1Test
{
    /**
     * Attempt 1 - use a DirectProcessor and send items to it.
     * Doesn't work though - seems to always run on the main thread.
     */
    @Test
    public void testReact1() throws InterruptedException
    {
        // Create the flux and sink.
        FluxProcessor<String, String> fluxProcessor = DirectProcessor.<String>create().serialize();
        FluxSink<String> sink = fluxProcessor.sink();

        // Create the pipeline.
        fluxProcessor
            .doOnNext(str -> showDebugMsg(str))   // What thread do ops work on?
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .subscribe(str -> showDebugMsg(str)); // What thread does subscribe run on?

        // Give the multi-thread pipeline a second.
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        // Time passes ... things happen ...
        // Pass a few messages to the sink, emulating events.
        sink.next("a");
        sink.next("b");
        sink.next("c");

        // It's multi-thread so wait a sec to receive.
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    // Used down below during Flux.create().
    private FluxSink<String> sink2;

    /**
     * Attempt 2 - use Flux.create() and its FluxSink object.
     * Also seems to always run on the main thread.
     */
    @Test
    public void testReact2() throws InterruptedException
    {
        // Create the flux and sink.
        Flux.<String>create(sink -> sink2 = sink)
            .doOnNext(str -> showDebugMsg(str))   // What thread do ops work on?
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .subscribe(str -> showDebugMsg(str)); // What thread does subscribe run on?

        // Give the multi-thread pipeline a second.
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        // Pass a few messages to the sink.
        sink2.next("a");
        sink2.next("b");
        sink2.next("c");

        // It's multi-thread so wait a sec to receive.
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    // Show us what thread we're on.
    private static void showDebugMsg(String msg)
    {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s [%s]", msg, Thread.currentThread().getName()));
    }
}
```

Output is always:

```
a [main]
a [main]
b [main]
b [main]
c [main]
c [main]
```

But what I would expect, is:

```
a [elastic-1]
a [elastic-1]
b [elastic-2]
b [elastic-2]
c [elastic-3]
c [elastic-3]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You see `[main]` because you're calling `onNext` from the main thread.
`subscribeOn` you're using is only for the subscription (when `create`'s lambda is triggered).
You will see `elastic-*` threads logged if you use `publishOn` instead of `subscribeOn`.

Also, consider using [Processors](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#processors), storing `sink` obtained from `Flux.create` and similar operators as a field is discouraged.

Comment: Shouldn't at least the `subscribe()` lambda run on the `subscribeOn()` Scheduler? And even when I do add `publishOn()`, it publishes every item on the same thread, e.g., `elastic-1`. Also the `testReact1()` method is using a Processor. Thanks.

Comment: it should and will, but you are not logging anything in `create`.

Comment: "the same thread" you observe is expected due to queue draining. Why would it spread if everything can de done on one thread?

Comment: Can you provide a reference to confirm "Also, consider using Processors, storing sink as a field is discouraged." ? IIUC, https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/ says the opposite: " Do I Need a Processor? Could a “generator” operator work instead? (Generally, these operators are made to bridge APIs that are not reactive, providing a “sink” that is similar in concept to a Processor, in the sense that it lets you manually populate the sequence with data or terminate it).". So using Flux.create( sink -> /*store the sink*/ ).publish().connect() is the recommended approach ?

Comment: the link you provided is pretty aligned with what I said. Storing `sink` obtained from `Flux.create` is a no go and should never be used / recommended.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Can you point me to the exact section that says we shouldn't store the sink ? I don't understand why it should be avoided

Comment: There is no such section in the docs, but, as one of Project Reactor developers, I can assure you that escaping `sink` from `Flux.create` is wrong. It will break on re-subscription (e.g. `retry`). There are `Processor`s for that.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Maybe this should be stated more clearly in the docs, even add an example for this case? I find it surprising that you would need a Processor (publisher and subscriber) when you only programmatically inject messages and don't subscribe to another publisher? In my use case, I have a spring controller rest endpoint (single method called in parallel from multiple http threads) which must emit events to a single Flux (the flux is returned to spring cloud stream to send messages to a rabbitmq server). Which processor is recommended in this case ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @bsideup How is storing the sink in a field different than creating a listener object capturing the sink like in this example from the docs: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.create ? In both cases the sink escapes the create lambda ? Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `parallel()` and `runOn()` instead of `subscribeOn()` to get `sink.next()` to run multi-threaded.
- bsideup is also correct - you can use `publishOn()` to coerce downstream operators to run on one different Scheduler thread.

Here is my updated code:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import reactor.core.publisher.DirectProcessor;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.FluxProcessor;
import reactor.core.publisher.FluxSink;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

/**
 * I want to construct my React pipelines during creation,
 * then emit events over the lifetime of my services.
 */
public class React1Test
{
    /**
     * Version 1 - use a DirectProcessor to dynamically emit items.
     */
    @Test
    public void testReact1() throws InterruptedException
    {
        // Create the flux and sink.
        FluxProcessor<String, String> fluxProcessor = DirectProcessor.<String>create().serialize();
        FluxSink<String> sink = fluxProcessor.sink();

        // Create the pipeline.
        fluxProcessor
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .doOnNext(str -> showDebugMsg(str))   // What thread do ops work on?
            .subscribe(str -> showDebugMsg(str)); // What thread does subscribe run on?

        // Give the multi-thread pipeline a second.
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        // Time passes ... things happen ...
        // Pass a few messages to the sink, emulating events.
        sink.next("a");
        sink.next("b");
        sink.next("c");

        // It's multi-thread so wait a sec to receive.
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    // Used down below during Flux.create().
    private FluxSink<String> sink2;

    /**
     * Version 2 - use Flux.create() and its FluxSink object.
     */
    @Test
    public void testReact2() throws InterruptedException
    {
        // Create the flux and sink.
        Flux.<String>create(sink -> sink2 = sink)
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .doOnNext(str -> showDebugMsg(str))   // What thread do ops work on?
            .subscribe(str -> showDebugMsg(str)); // What thread does subscribe run on?

        // Give the multi-thread pipeline a second.
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        // Pass a few messages to the sink.
        sink2.next("a");
        sink2.next("b");
        sink2.next("c");

        // It's multi-thread so wait a sec to receive.
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    // Show us what thread we're on.
    private static void showDebugMsg(String msg)
    {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s [%s]", msg, Thread.currentThread().getName()));
    }
}
```

Both versions produce the desired multi-threaded output:

```
a [elastic-2]
b [elastic-3]
c [elastic-4]
b [elastic-3]
a [elastic-2]
c [elastic-4]
```

Comment: The answer is not related to your question. You never asked for multi-threading.

Comment: You're right, that's why I didn't mark it as the official answer, and also why I mentioned bsideup's perfectly good answer. There are two ways (so far) to use a sink outside of the lambda - use `.publishOn()` or use `.parallel()` with `.runOn()`. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Although `parallel` + `runOn` combination works, it is not for what it is designed. If you need to move the computation to another thread, `publishOn` is the operator that should be used.

Comment: The `parallel` + `runOn` combination is the only version that puts each item on a separate thread from the pool. `publishOn` and `subscribeOn` move the computation for all items to a single separate thread. If you know a better way to accomplish this, please let me know!