# FluxSink seems to be queing things

Tags: project-reactor

For testing purposes, I want to send only one thing at a time, but the thing(s) that FluxSink is sending to the other side do not match the think that I literally just called the FluxSink.next method with.  The thing(s) that it is sending over are things that were "nexted" a while ago.  Is there any way to prevent FluxSink from doing any kind of queing/batching or to set the queue/batch size to 1, just like I'm setting my batch size to one for my test?

Comment: It depends how do you consume data downstream. Reactor API controls backpressure by requesting data from upstream. Many operators such as `flatMap` supports concurrency and prefetch settings. Use `log()` operator to understand more about requests and reactive signals.

Comment: Thanks @Alex !  Can you give an example?

Comment: @Alex would I have to change the consuming side to only consume one thing at a time?

Comment: I would be useful if you share more details about your implementation.

Comment: @Alex it's quite complicated code, so I can't share all the details.....basically, it boils down to this.....

In the publisher, we are calling FluxSink.next and on the subscriber, onNext is called with an object that doesn't match what was just "nexted" at the publisher.

Comment: Could you create a small example that just shows the "problem". Also please check [Backpressure](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactive.backpressure).

Comment: ```
    @Override
    public void onNext(Operation operation) {
        this.distributor.distribute(operation).toFuture().whenComplete((value, e) -> {
            if (receivedCount.incrementAndGet() == this.requestSize) {
                this.receivedCount.set(0);
                this.subscription.request(this.requestSize);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @Alex So, just for kicks, I changed request(this.requestSize) to request(1000) (requestSize was 1) in the above code on the subscriber side and now the subscriber does not fall behind even though the publisher is only "nexting" 1 thing at a time.  I'm not sure why this code was written this way.  I'll see if I can figure that out and what might be a better way to write this.

Comment: @Alex Now, the only thing I'm concerned about is whether it's possible for a consumer to request TOO MUCH work from the producer or whether reactor will be smart enough to handle things properly.  Do you know off the top of your head?  I'll try to contrive a test to determine that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clearly understood what you're going to achieve, so it what I'm guessing base on title:

You may use [`FluxSink.OverflowStrategy`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.html) but there no strategy to block `FluxSink.next`, because reactive programming is NOT about blocking programming and if producer in reactive programming is faster that consumer, reactive programming wil take care and will `BUFFER|DROP` etc. so You have to speed up Your consumer or choose appropriate `FluxSink.OverflowStrategy`.

Think how You will implement it without reactive programming. If your producer is faster than consumer you probably will queue data from producer or throw an error, because data are too old.

Anyway, probably the best choice in Your case will be `Flux.create` or `Flux.generate` [Difference Between Flux.create and Flux.generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951060/difference-between-flux-create-and-flux-generate)

Remember: `Flux.generate` is created to **calculate and emit values on demand**, so you may put `BlockingQueue.poll()` inside - it's not what I recommend, but it sth what You probably looking for.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!  I was able to determine that the subscriber was not requesting enough work from the producer and was therefore falling behind the producer.  See the comment I added in response to my original post.  Now, the only thing I'm concerned about is whether it's possible for a consumer to request TOO MUCH work from the producer or whether reactor will be smart enough to handle things properly.

Comment: Flux producer will accept element on demand, unless some overflow strategy it's specified. Take a look at `Flux.onBackpressureBuffer()`